# Overloading operator<< c++; undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream

Tags: c++, g++, operator-overloading, undefined

I am trying to overload operator<< in my code. If I comment out the lines where I try to use the << operator with my custom class, it compiles fine. The error almost looks like it doesn't like the c++ libraries (?).

All my research on this problem has stated that it is a linking problem. Most suggest using g++ instead of gcc. I am using g++ as my compiler, and I get this error still.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//prototype the class and the functions
template<class T> class strange;
template<class T> ostream& operator<< (ostream& osObject, strange<T>& sObject);


//begin class
template <class T>
class strange
{
    public:
        // .... function prototypes go here.
            strange(T x,T y);
            friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& osObject, strange<T>& sObject);

    private:
    T a;
    T b;
};
// .... your function definitions go here
template <class T>
        strange<T>::strange(T first, T second){
        a = first;
        b = second;
}

template <class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& osObject, const strange<T>& sObject){
        osObject << sObject.a << ", " << sObject.b;
        return osObject;
}



int main()
{
    strange<int> x1(4,6) , x2(12,2) ;
    //strange<char> y1('m','n') , y2('m','n') ;
    cout << "x1 = " << x1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& operator<< <int>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, strange<int>&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Could it be that your operator definition is in a `.cpp` file and not in a header?

Comment: Wouldn't 
    '#include <iostream>;'
and
    'using namespace std;'
take care of that (for the ostream&)?

Comment: No, *your* template code must be accessible via includes.

Comment: At this point, I only have one .cpp file since its a small project. I'll move things to seperate headers when I get the whole thing working.

Comment: It's not a linking problem, although the message suggests that. The problem is that, for whatever reason, the template for <<(ostream&, Strange<T>&) is not being seen.

Comment: Have I declared it out of scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made two changes, one to the friend definition, and one to the prototype. This should compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//prototype the class and the functions
template<class T> class strange;
template<class T> ostream& operator<< (ostream& osObject, const strange<T>& sObject);


//begin class
template <class T>
class strange
{
    public:
        // .... function prototypes go here.
            strange(T x,T y);
            friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& osObject, const strange<T>& sObject);

    private:
    T a;
    T b;
};
// .... your function definitions go here
template <class T>
        strange<T>::strange(T first, T second){
        a = first;
        b = second;
}

template <class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& osObject, const strange<T>& sObject){
        osObject << sObject.a << ", " << sObject.b;
        return osObject;
}



int main()
{
    strange<int> x1(4,6) , x2(12,2) ;
    //strange<char> y1('m','n') , y2('m','n') ;
    cout << "x1 = " << x1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this compiles in clang, g++ and at [ideone](http://ideone.com/mCBuC)

To explain the issue, the compiler is looking at link time for a definition for:

```
 std::ostream & operator<< <int>(std::ostream &, strange<int>&);
```

When you only have a definition for:

```
 std::ostream & operator<< <int>(std::ostream &, strange<int> const &);
```

This is because of the miscommunication between your prototypes (both the explicit one and the friend) and your definition.

Comment: Trying it now... "friend used outside of class"

Comment: Weird. compiles with clang, not with g++. Give me a few more minutes.

Comment: Maybe you are seeing the same thing I am... if I delete line 6, it gives a number of extra errors, even implementing the change you suggested. I also prototyped up there because for whatever reason, it wouldn't compile without it.

Comment: @Jeff: Here's a new go at it. I made sure to test with g++ this time.

Comment: Works beautifully! I am still unsure why I need the 'const' on all of those in the first place... Shouldn't it compile without them (since I am telling the compiler what these classes take as input)?

Comment: I should think you would need the `const` everywhere or nowhere, as long as its consistent.  However, its better with `const` everywhere so that it would still work when called from a `const` method.

Comment: The issue is that the type `strange<int> &` is different from `strange<int> const &` In your prototype, you told the compiler that in some compilation unit, there would be a definition for your usage of the `strange<int> &` variant. However, you only ever tried to create implementations of the `strange<int> const &` variant. In this particular use case, you can remove const from all __3__ places. This would still compile. However, you would not be able to do `cout << strange<int>(3,4);`, because that would need either a pass by value, or pass by const reference.

Comment: why the `<>` after `operator <<` in the declaration?  the editor in Qt underlines this as an error, yet this was the magic ingredient that got Visual C++ to link it successfully.